# Why does Django AssertFormError throw a TypeError: argument of type 'property' is not iterable?

Tags: django, python-3.x, unit-testing

I'd like some help or advice on how to test for errors in one of my Django forms.  It's responsible for ensuring the user enters a valid session ID which is used as a authentication token for a 3rd party API.  Valid IDs are 32 characters long and alphanumerical.

I've chosen an approach that validates the field, rather than the model.

When I manually test this using the development server it works as expected. I.E. if the user pastes a string of the wrong length or with the special characters, the field's validate method creates errors which are then displayed via a for loop around the form errors in the html template.

I don't understand the following error.  I've temporarily modified testcases.py to prove that the errors are being passed to it - so why is context[form].errors a 'property' and how did it get there?

I'm using Django 1.10 and Python 3.5.1

```
======================================================================
ERROR: test_index_sessid_short_strings (poe.tests.TestBannerButtons)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/adam.green/Documents/workspace/poe-client/poetools_project/poe/tests.py", line 105, in test_index_sessid_short_strings
    self.assertFormError(response, 'form', "new_sessid" ,  'The Session ID needs to be exactly 32 characters long')
  File "/Users/adam.green/.virtualenvs/poe-tools/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/test/testcases.py", line 421, in assertFormError
    if field in context[form].errors:
TypeError: argument of type 'property' is not iterable

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.805s
```

**test**

```
def test_index_sessid_short_strings(self):
    url = reverse('index')
    response = self.client.post(url, {'new_sessid': "f14"}) 
    self.assertFormError(response, 'form', "new_sessid" ,  'The Session ID needs to be exactly 32 characters long')
```

**form.py**

```
class SessID(forms.Field):

    def validate(self, session_id):
        """Check if value consists only of valid emails."""
        # Use the parent's handling of required fields, etc.
        super().validate(session_id)
        if len(session_id) < 32 > len(session_id):
            raise ValidationError(
                                  _('The Session ID needs to be exactly 32 characters long'),
                                  code = 'sessid wrong length'
                                  )
        if not re.match("^[A-Za-z0-9]*$", session_id):
            raise ValidationError(
                                  _('The Session ID should only have letters and numbers, no special characters'),
                                  code = 'sessid not alphanumeric'
                                  )        


class ResetSessID(forms.ModelForm):
    new_sessid = SessID()
    #forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'special', 'size': '32'})                        )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ResetSessID, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        stdlogger.info("init of ResetSessID")
        #print("dir")#, self.fields.items['new_sessid'])
        if kwargs.get('instance'):
            new_sessid = kwargs['instance'].new_essid
            stdlogger.info("inner kwargs loop")
        return super(ResetSessID, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        model = PoeAccount
        exclude = ("acc_name", "sessid")

    def clean(self):
        if 'reg_button' in self.data:
            print("amazing")
```

**views.py**

```
def index(request):
    request.session.set_test_cookie()
    item_category_list = ItemCategory.objects.all()
    modifications_list = FixCategory.objects.all()
    context_dict = {}
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = ResetSessID(request.POST)    
            if form.is_valid():
                # get the right account
                me = poe.models.PoeAccount.objects.get(
                        acc_name = request.user.poeuser.poe_account_name
                        )
                # commit new sessid passed to here
               # me.full_clean()
                me.sessid = form['new_sessid'].value()
                me.save(update_fields=['sessid'])
                context_dict["old_sessid"] = me.sessid
                context_dict['form'] = ResetSessID
                response = render(request,'poe/index.html', context_dict)
                #return response
            else:
                context_dict['errors'] = form.errors
                print("form has errors", form.errors)
                me = poe.models.PoeAccount.objects.get(
                        acc_name = request.user.poeuser.poe_account_name
                        )
                context_dict['errors'] = form.errors
                context_dict["old_sessid"] = me.sessid
                context_dict['form'] = ResetSessID
                for x, y in form.errors.items():
                    print("errors", x, y)
                response = render(request,'poe/index.html', context_dict)
                #return response

        else:
            context_dict = {'form': ResetSessID}
            me = poe.models.PoeAccount.objects.get(acc_name = request.user.poeuser.poe_account_name)
            context_dict["old_sessid"] = me.sessid

    context_dict.update({'item_categories': item_category_list, 'mods': modifications_list})
    # make sure the session keeps track of the number of visits
    visits = request.session.get('visits')
    if not visits:
        visits = 1
    reset_last_visit_time = False
    last_visit = request.session.get('last_visit')
    if last_visit:
        last_visit_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(last_visit[:-7], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        if (datetime.datetime.now() - last_visit_time).seconds > 0:
            # ...reassign the value of the cookie to +1 of what it was before...
            visits = visits + 1
            # ...and update the last visit cookie, too.
            reset_last_visit_time = True
    else:
        # Cookie last_visit doesn't exist, so create it to the current date/time.
        reset_last_visit_time = True
    # make sure the session keeps track of time last visited
    if reset_last_visit_time:
        request.session['last_visit'] = str(datetime.datetime.now())
        request.session['visits'] = visits
    context_dict['visits'] = visits

    #print("context_dict", context_dict)
    response = render(request,'poe/index.html', context_dict)

    return response
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you are setting the `form` context variable in your view to be your form **class** itself, rather than an **instance** of that class.

Replace:

`context_dict['form'] = ResetSessID`

with:

`context_dict['form'] = form`

where `form` is the variable you define just above your `form.is_valid()` check. Do this in both branches if your `form.is_valid()` block.

Same thing for the outer if block as well:

```
# Not a post request
context_dict = {'form': ResetSessID()}   # Note brackets
```

The view you currently have would not work at all as far as I can see - it may be worth getting it working before you write tests for it.